# How to edit rails app in production env, specifically CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I tried to edit my CSS which was working in production mode but after a made a few changes the fonts weren't loading. I did a hard reset on my git and rolled back to the previews commit. I'm wondering what the best way of editing sites in production is. Do I have to precompile assets everytime I make a change in my CSS? I did this and ended up having loads of issues. I also tried deleting the public/assets folder and then assets:precompile but nothing worked.

Comment: How do you release/deploy to production? Also which Rails version?

Comment: Rails 4, I'm using a box on Nitrous.IO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already running the Rails application in production u need to run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Dont forget to use RAILS_ENV=production. After precompiling Old Assets will be replaced by the new ones

You might also need to edit config/environments/production.rb file and modify as following

```
config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.compress = false

config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Added clarification: though the Old Assets will be replaced in usage, they will still exist in the public assets folder. I recommend also performing a cleanup: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clean`

Answer (score 2):

In Production Environment after editing the CSS the assets need to be precompiled. Run the following command to precompile the assets

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

please refer the following link for more information
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Comment: every time I edit them? what about the old assets in public folder? Will the be overwritten? I did `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` without `RAILS_ENV=production` does that make a difference?